# How to add existing Template to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Particularly for VS.NET 2013, how do you add a template?  I've created a custom template. VS.NET adds it to \Libraries\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates.  I'd like to know import that template into VS.NET on a different machine.

When I rename the zip template in the above location, that name doesn't show up in the add new item dialogue box in VS.NET.  Are there any steps for adding a template?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the template to [Visual Studio installation path]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\  of the other machine.

And then run the command `devenv /installvstemplates` in your Developer Command Prompt

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279.aspx